# Why does perforce show "//depot <contains no files or folders>"?

Tags: perforce

Starting yesterday I have been unable to connect to our Perforce server. Expanding the depot gives the message "//depot ". Funny because I connected just fine last week and the folks sitting next to me can connect without problems.

IT says nothing the settings have not changed and no errors are being reported. It doesn't help that IT is multiple time zones away!

I'm hoping someone here has seen a similar problem and can tell me which switch to flip.

**SOLVED:** Using P4Win or P4V there are no errors. BUT using the command line p4.exe I get the error "protected namespace - access denied". Passed this onto IT and perforce mysteriously works again. Sounds like I got my permissions disabled and then re-enabled. No-one has owned up to anything but at least I'm up and running again!

Funny that I had to go to the command line before I got an error message.

Comment: Do you use p4v or p4? Does the error manifest with both?

Comment: Have you changed *anything* recently? It sounds like you client spec mappings might be wrong.

Comment: Do you have the Log pane opened in p4v?  I would think you would have been able to see these errors in the log.

Comment: @Chance, yes the log windows were open for p4v and p4win - I would have expected to see the errors there too, but nothing.

Answer (score 3):

"protected namespace - access denied" - means you have no permissions for the specified path. You should see this message in P4V output window if you have the detailed logging enabled.

One possibility is an administrator may have accidentally introduced a typo in your username whilst editing a group or the protection table, or removed you from a group, essentially removing your access (but easy to restore). The spec depot keeps changes to perforce server control files so an administrator could check to see what went wrong, but the spec depot does not tell you which administrator changed it. The spec depot must be created before the event.